# How to set automatic attribute labels for multilingual site in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I have a multilingual web site and I don't know how many languages will there be. I'm using codemix/yii2-localeurls extension and field name consist of inputName_languageCode. For example: title_fr, title_en, content_fr, content_en etc. So how I can do in my model smth like that:

```
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'title_*' => 'Title',
        'content_*' => 'Content',
    ];
}
```

Where (*) - is any language code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return [
    'title_'.yii::$app->language => 'Title',
    'content_'.yii::$app->language => 'Content',
];
```

According to your OP. Still using Yii 2 Internationalization is recommended

Comment: what is the issue ?

Comment: Actually the yii::$app->language is always is default language. So in the attributeLabels we get always smtn like that `'title_en` (if default language EN). But in my view file there are simultaneously fields which name like this: 

```$form->field($model, 'title')->textInput(['maxlength' => 255]);```
```$form->field($model, 'title_en')->textInput(['maxlength' => 255]);```
```$form->field($model, 'title_fr')->textInput(['maxlength' => 255]);``` At the same time

Comment: in that case loop through the languages you have

Comment: Yes, I know this way and it will work. But I thought there is a more concise solution. 
Anyway, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Key in this array is column name, so it should't be renamed. To multilanguage translations you should use `Yii::t('category', 'text_to_translate')` - docs here:[Yii 2 Internationalization](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-i18n.html)

For example:

```
return [
    'title' => Yii::t('app', 'title_label'),
    'content' => Yii::t('app', 'content_label'),
];
```

Comment: Yep. I know this way but I thought that there is another way to do my task

Comment: Propably its the easiest way.

Comment: Is there have more ideas?